# Web service bug in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I have the following web service method (.ASMX file):

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public GetTruckBasicReturnedObject GetPollBasic(ulong truckId)
{
    return new GetTruckBasicReturnedObject();
}
```

Any time I uncomment this method, when I try to get to the service test page, I get my site's default error page.
Just below that I have another service method, with the same attributes that works just fine. 
I triple checked to see all my classes are declared, and anyhow I don't get any compilation error.
Class GetTruckBasicReturnedObject has an empty constructor.
We recently migrated from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 but as I said, there is another very similar web method, on the same class, that works fine.

The other method that works:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public SignInReturnedObject SignIn(string userName, string password)
{
  cLogin login = new cLogin(LocalizationSettings.CurrentDataCenter);
  UInt64 uiUserId;

  //Session is created in the below method!
  RegistrationCodes rc = login.LoginUser(userName, password, (ulong)Channels.TolunaChannel, out uiUserId);
  return new SignInReturnedObject(convertFromRegistrationCodesToRegistrationErrorTypes(rc));
}
```

The Class:

```
using System;
using dPolls.Objects;


namespace API
{

public class GetTruckBasicReturnedObject
{

    public TruckBasic truckBasic { get; set; }        //public for debugging reasons

    public ErrorTypes Error { get; set;}            //public for debugging reasons


    public GetTruckBasicReturnedObject()
    {
    }


    public GetTruckBasicReturnedObject(User user, ulong pollId)
    {
        Error = ErrorTypes.None;
        try
        {
            truckBasic = new TruckBasic(user, pollId);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Log.WriteError("Unable to retrieve truck. Exception-{0}",exception);
            Error = ErrorTypes.General;
        }
    }
}
```

}

What could it be? (Is there any information missing in my question? If so, what is it?) 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked in the event logs for exceptions from the web service?

Comment: Can you show the `GetTruckBasicReturnedObject` class and/or the other method that works?

Comment: @Oded: Sorry for the ignorance, but where is the event log? Thanks.

Comment: @Oren A, you could use the [Event Viewer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0404snow/WindowsEventViewer.jpg), but the best would be to show your code as @M4N suggested. Also what exception are you getting?

Comment: @Oren A: One service can not have two entry points which listen the same URL: There can be only one! (like at "Highlander") So You should verify, that the second method with [WebMethod] attribute has another name or commented if you uncomment this version of `GetPollBasic` method.

Comment: @Darin. I don't get an exception, I'm being re-directed to the default error page.

Comment: @Oren A, could you show the code for the WebService as well?

Comment: @Oren: I see you ask a lot of ASMX questions, but also that you say you're a newbie. Were you aware that Microsoft now considers ASMX to be a "legacy technology", and that all development should be using WCF?

Comment: I'm aware of that, but a lecturer of mine who uses WCF a lot told me that if I won't take a WCF full blown course, I'm better off not using it. And I'm on a "bit" time pressure at work, hence I don't use WCF (and also hence all the questions..). But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your lecturer is cheating you. Most people don't have to take a "full-blown course" before using WCF or anything else. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info to get started. A lot of your questions would already have been answered if you weren't using legacy technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was the name of the page I requested the web service from. it was "default", which caused ISAPI to kick into very unwanted action. Renaming the page solved the problem.

Thanks again to all replayers.